# Giving error "Received authentication is null" when try to post a tweet?

Tags: android, twitter, callback, twitter4j

I am working on a very simple android twitter app but when i try to post a tweet on twitter it gives me the received authentication is null error and on and in android 4.1 it force closes the app i searched the web but didnt found any help

```
enter public class StatusClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button update;
Twitter twitter;
ConfigurationBuilder cb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.update_status);
    update = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUpdate);
    update.setOnClickListener(this);
    cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("My_Consumer_key");
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("My_Consumer_secret_key");
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken("My_Oath_access_token");
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("My_Token_secret");
     twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();   
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



        String tweet="HELLO WORLD!";
        try {
            Status status = twitter.updateStatus(tweet);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }






}
```

}

```
 W/System.err( 1798):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1153)
```

Comment: looks like your login is failing, ensure that your keys are all accurate.

Comment: everything is perfect

Comment: do you have internet access in your app? i.e. do you have the permission and are you making your network calls on a background thread?

Comment: i am not making any calls on the background thread please guide me how to make calls

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the code below?:

```
AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
OAuthAuthorization authorization = new OAuthAuthorization(ConfigurationContext.getInstance(), CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, accessToken);
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(authorization);
```

Also try the basic authorization:

```
Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.setOAuthConsumerKey("your_customer_key")
.setOAuthConsumerSecret("your_customer_secret")
.build();

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance(new BasicAuthorization("username", "password"));
AccessToken token = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
```

Comment: it is not working its still giving error "Received authentication is null" please help....If you have any example code on the latest twitter api please let me know